# How to pass multiple custom field values to Analytics

Tags: javascript, wordpress, analytics, custom-fields

In my site, like most, pages can be tagged with tags/categories.

We have an internal rule / sanity check that a piece can only have a max of three tags.

The issue is being able to determine which are the most popular in terms of pageviews as Google Analytics doesn't allow you to pass multple values as a custom field value or as an event value.

What I'd like to achieve is to add a dimension to Analytics so as to be able to report which are the most popular categories/tags.

Our tag structure is hierarchical like so:

```
-Top Level Tag
--Secondary Level Tag 1
--Secondary Level Tag 2
--Secondary Level Tag 3
-Top Level Tag
--Another Tag 
and so on...
```

At the moment, it seems the only way is to pass single values, ala:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',4,'categories','culture theatres',3]);
```

Where as I'd like to pass an array of values, like:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',4,'categories', ['culture', 'theatres'],3]);
```

Anyone know a workaround or whether it's possible to do so? The docs don't give me hope...